# doctype declaration in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

I'm trying to repoduce in Jade following output code (incluiding carriage returns) with no success:

Trying to output following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE j:jelly 
[
  <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
  <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
  <!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;">
  <!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;">
  <!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;">
  <!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;">
  <!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;">
  <!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">
]>
```

in **Jade code** I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
doctype j:jelly[<!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;"><!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;"><!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;"><!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;"><!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;"><!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;"><!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;"><!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;"><!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;"> ]
```

which outputs one-only line (working but messy, no carriage returns):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE j:jelly [<!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;"><!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;"><!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;"><!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;"><!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;"><!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;"><!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;"><!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just add line breaks with raw text:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
| < doctype j:jelly
| [
|  <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
|  <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
|  <!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;">
|  <!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;">
|  <!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;">
|  <!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;">
|  <!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;">
|  <!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;">
|  <!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">
| ]>
```

to get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
< doctype j:jelly
[
 <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
 <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
 <!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;">
 <!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;">
 <!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;">
 <!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;">
 <!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;">
 <!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;">
 <!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">
]>
```

Because this is using only raw text you may consider to use the include statement.

With

**start.jade**:

```
include ./other.jade
```

and

**other.jade**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
< doctype j:jelly
[
 <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
 <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
 <!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;">
 <!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;">
 <!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;">
 <!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;">
 <!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;">
 <!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;">
 <!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">
]>
```

You will get

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js:240
  throw err;
        ^
Error: other.jade:3
    1| <?xml version="1.0"?> 
    2| < doctype j:jelly
  > 3| [
    4|  <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
    5|  <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
    6|  <!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;">

unexpected text [
 <!
    at Object.Lexer.fail (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:887:11)
    at Object.Lexer.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:947:15)
    at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:113:46)
    at Parser.lookahead (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:102:23)
    at Parser.peek (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:79:17)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:117:26)
    at Parser.parseInclude (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:616:22)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:223:21)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:122:25)
    at parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:104:21)
```

because the to be included file is interpreted as jade template. Just rename it.

With

**start.jade**:

```
include ./other.inc
```

and

**other.inc**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
< doctype j:jelly
[
 <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
 <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
 <!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;">
 <!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;">
 <!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;">
 <!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;">
 <!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;">
 <!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;">
 <!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">
]>
```

You will get the expected

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
< doctype j:jelly
[
 <!ENTITY aacute "&#x000E1;">
 <!ENTITY Aacute "&#x000C1;">
 <!ENTITY eacute "&#x000E9;">
 <!ENTITY ordm "&#x000BA;">
 <!ENTITY euro "&#x020AC;">
 <!ENTITY amp  "&#x00026;">
 <!ENTITY iquest  "&#x000BF;">
 <!ENTITY iexcl  "&#x000A1;">
 <!ENTITY copy  "&#x000A9;">
]>
```

Comment: Hi Sascha. Not really working. Whenever I type a pipe: | and error arised when compiling ("Unexpected text". I assume you have to place some text after |). Also, notice I need to get:
 <!DOCTYPE j:jelly whatever (no closing tag yet)
<!DOCTYPE j:jelly> whatever (in your example tag would close ahead of time)

Comment: Last edit will do the trick :) Thanks a lot for your answer and time Sascha. 

This issue also made me think if it's possible in jade insert \n\r between attributes in a same tag. 

Sometimes in a project the back end dynamically outputs many data- attributes to a DIV (i.e) and for legibility is good to feed new line to visually see the code better. Examle: <div id="myId" data-reference="whatever" data-prize="somePrize" data-instock="yes" ... But I guess that would be another question :)